# Printing first occurence of multiple files with awk

Tags: awk

I have .txt files in subdirectories and I wish to extract the first occurrence of a string in the 4th column in the line where the string "CHEESE" is contained.

The code I am using is below:

```
awk '/CHEESE/{print $4}' ./*/*/*.txt | pr -15s',' > ofile.csv
```

This one does not work because it prints ALL occurrences of the string in the specific columns of all files.

I tried adding the 'exit' as below:

```
awk '/CHEESE/{print $4;exit;}' ./*/*/*.txt | pr -15s',' > ofile.csv
```

This printed one occurrence - but only in one file.

How can I make this print only one occurrence for all files?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk '/CHEESE/ && f!=1 {print $4;f=1}' ./*/*/*.txt | pr -15s',' > ofile.csv
```

It will only print if `f` is not set.  When find `CHEESE`, set `f`, so no more printing

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gawk, you can try the `nextfile` statement.